# Does Citrus Automation Framework support AssertSoapFault function with Java Dsl?

Tags: citrus-framework

I tried making my own sytax but didn't get anywhere.

Assertsoapfault().faultcode("try").when(soap().client("endpoint").send());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the default Java DSL method provided by Citrus:

```
assertSoapFault()
     .faultCode("SOAP-ENV:Server")
     .faultString("Internal server error")
     .when(soap().client("endpoint")
                 .send());
```

Comment: Thanks Chris !! I was trying without providing faultCode and faultString.